# How many days belong to a certain range of dates?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Let's say I have a start `DateTime` object containing 2012/09/21 23:59:59 and an end `DateTime` object containing 2012/09/22 00:01:02. The difference between these two objects is little more than a minute, but the number of days belonging to this range of dates is equal to 2.

I have read other similar questions, and I think that `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` classes do not provide methods to perform this type of calculation. How to calculate the number of days belonging to a certain range of dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.Parse("2012/09/21 23:59:59");
DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.Parse("2012/09/22 00:01:02");
TimeSpan difference = dateTime1 - dateTime2;
```

The variable `difference` contains the time between the two dates. For example use the [TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) property to get the difference in days.

If you want to exclude the time portion, use the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property on DateTime, for example:

```
TimeSpan difference = dateTime1.Date - dateTime2.Date;
```

TotalDays will be 1 in this case rather than 0.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! The difference between the two `Date` properties: `int n = (int)((dateTime2.Date - dateTime1.Date).TotalDays) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
System.DateTime dtTodayNoon = new System.DateTime(2006, 9, 13, 12, 0, 0);
System.DateTime dtTodayMidnight = new System.DateTime(2006, 9, 13, 0, 0, 0);
System.TimeSpan diffResult = dtTodayNoon.Subtract(dtYestMidnight);
Console.WriteLine("Yesterday Midnight - Today Noon = " + diffResult.Days);
Console.WriteLine("Yesterday Midnight - Today Noon = " + diffResult.TotalDays);
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you want to include the daylight savings:

```
System.TimeSpan diffResult = dtTodayNoon.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(dtYestMidnight.ToUniversalTime());
```

You could use DateTimeOffSet too if timezones are important

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
(dateTime2 - dateTime1).TotalDays
```

work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> I have read other similar questions, and I think that TimeSpan and
>   DateTime classes do not provide methods to perform this type of
>   calculation.

Of course that they do.

[TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) is the class to use. I guess you are looking for the [TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) property, aren't you?

```
DateTime date1 = ...;
DateTime date2 = ...;
TimeSpan difference = date2 - date1;
int totalNumberOfDays = difference.TotalDays;
```